# jQuery .load content then .toggle it without ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a button. When I click on it  content loads. When I click on it after content toggles (display: none). But it still sending ajax requests.

How to check If the content was loaded to start toggling without ajax requests?

```
<div id="morechan">
    <a id="btnC" href="#" title="Kanalu saraksts"><i class="icon-caret-down"></i></a>
</div>
<div id="channel-list">
</div><!-- end channel-list -->

(function($) {
  $("#btnC").click(function() {
    $('#channel-list').html('loading...').load('channels.html');
  }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you include the code in your question?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your jquery code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest setting a data attribute and testing for it and prevent load if it is not set

```
$("#btnC").click(function() {
   if( typeof( $('#channel-list').data("contentLoaded") ) != "undefined" ) {
       //Do toggle code here.
       return;
   } else {
       //Do load code here.
       $('#channel-list').load("http://www.someurl.com",function() {
          $(this).data("contentLoaded",true);
       });
   }
});
```

Set `contentLoaded` to `false` when/if needing to reload content and check to see if its `true` or `false` in the click event.

```
var contentLoaded = $('#channel-list').data("contentLoaded");
if( typeof( contentLoaded ) != "undefined" && contentLoaded ) {
   //Do toggle code here.
   return;
}
```